# Changing Latitude Values in a netCDF4 file

Tags: python, dictionary, latitude-longitude, netcdf, netcdf4

I am a climate science student who is still relatively new to the netcdf4 world, and I am seriously struggling with a very tiny thing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I was given this nc file with dimensions latitude, longitude, class, but the latitude range is (0,180,1) instead of (-90,90,1). This means that any mapping is pretty much impossible, especially since I am working with another dataset that has the same grid size, but proper coordinates. I have tried creating a new netcdf4 with correct latitude values and passing the variable through, but it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It should be straightforward to create a new xarray dataset with the correct latitudes then write to netcdf. Please provide the code that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
ds['lat'] = ds['lat']-90
display(ds)
```

Comment: It would probably have to be more something like `if ds['lat'] > 90: ds['lat'] = ds['lat'] - 180`, to respect the meaning of latitudes.